# Запрос axios блокируется CORS Policy

Tags: php, axios, cors

Мне нужно отправить post запрос на мой сервер.
Запрос:

```
const data = {email: email, password: password, passwordConfirm: passwordConfirm, quest: quest};
axios({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/api/message",
    data: data
}).then(response => console.log(response));
```

index.php на сервере (просто возвращает полученные данные):

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

При отправке запроса в консоли появляется ошибка:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/api/message' from origin 
'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
header is present on the requested resource
```

При этом данные в консоли не появляются. Как исправить это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить
`header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin; http://localhost:3000");`

Comment: Спасибо, ваш совет на половину решил мою проблему. Я добавил в index.php строку header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000"); (вы совершили небольшую опечатку, вместо : написали  ;). После в консоли стало появляться новое сообщение CORS Policy, связанное с заголовком Access-Control-Allow-Headers. Это решилось добавлением header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type"); в файл index.php

Comment: @ert11, не знаю как вы скопировали, но опечатки я не вижу) У меня как раз `;`